# expected unqualified id before while c++

Tags: c++

I am making a simple C++ game based loosely on Starcraft. This is a way to practice pointers.

The program works fine so now im adding the little technical stuff in this case, the Cloaking ability ghost

In the ghost class, I set up a while loop for while bool cloak == true , you set the hits to blank as the ghost cant be hit while cloaked ( no detectors in this game) When i set it up, it gives me the error " expected unqualified id before while" .If i take out the loop, it doesnt give me an error.

any help is much appreciated

here is my ghost.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

#include "ghost.h"


ghost::ghost(string iname, string iteam, string itype, int Snipe, bool cloak)
                       : infantry(iname, iteam, itype)
{
    set_SniperR(Snipe);
    set_Cloak(cloak);
    set_health(80);  
}

void ghost::set_SniperR(int Snipe)
{
    SniperR = Snipe;
}

int ghost::get_SniperR() const
{
    return SniperR;
}

void ghost::shoot_SniperR(infantry* attacked_infantry)
{
    if(SniperR!=0 && this->get_health()!=0 && attacked_infantry->get_health()!=0)
    {
        attacked_infantry->SniperR_hit();
    }        
}

void ghost::attack(infantry* attacked_infantry)
{
    shoot_SniperR(attacked_infantry);

    if (attacked_infantry->get_health() == 0)
        attacked_infantry->die();     
}    

void ghost::heal(infantry* attacked_infantry) { }

void ghost::die()
{
   set_SniperR(0);
}

void ghost::set_Cloak(bool cloak)
{
    Cloak = cloak;
}

bool ghost::get_Cloak() const
{
    return Cloak;
}

while ( cloak) // <-- error
{
    void ghost::AssaultR_hit()
    {
        // when cloak is on , AssaultR doesnt affect Ghost
    }
    void ghost::FlameT_hit() { }

    void ghost::SniperR_hit() { }

    void ghost::RocketL_hit() { }

    void ghost::StickyG_hit() { }
}

void ghost::print() const
{
    cout << endl;
    infantry::print();
    cout << "Sniper Rifle Rounds: " << get_SniperR() << endl;        
}  

void ghost::speak() const
{
    infantry::speak();
    cout << "Did somebody call for an exterminator? " << endl;
}

void ghost::display() const
{
    infantry::display();
    cout << right << setw(5) << " "
         << right << setw(5) << " "
         << right << setw(10) << get_SniperR()
         << endl;    
}
```

Comment: You can't have a `while` outside of a function

Comment: Please learn to indent and use newlines responsibly and sensibly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to do this is to remove the while loop and check if cloak is true in your methods. Here is a implementation that will not give you the errors(assuming cloak is a member variable, which it should be in this case):

```
void ghost::AssaultR_hit()
{
    if(!cloak)
    {
       //assualtR_hit implementation goes here
    }
}
void ghost::FlameT_hit()
{
        if(!cloak)
    {
       //FlameT_hit implementation goes here
    }
}

void ghost::SniperR_hit()
{
    if(!cloak)
    {
       //SniperR_hit implementation goes here
    }

}

void ghost::RocketL_hit()
{
    if(!cloak)
    {
       //RocketL_hit implementation goes here
    }
}

void ghost::StickyG_hit()
{
    if(!cloak)
    {
       //StickyG_hit implementation goes here
    }
}
```

Note: Also note the comment that you can not have a while loop outside of a function in C++ like the commentator said.